# No puedo añadir más de una clave foránea en una sola tabla en SQL

Tags: sql, table

El problema aparece al crear la tabla venta.

```
CREATE DATABASE empresa;

use empresa;

CREATE table clientes

(

    nrocliente bigint(10) NOT NULL,

    nombre char(50),

    direccion char(100),

    PRIMARY KEY (nrocliente)

)
```

---

```
use empresa;

CREATE table producto

(

    codproducto int(5) NOT NULL,

    descrip text(100),

    precio int(10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (codproducto)

)
```

---

```
use empresa;

CREATE TABLE venta (

    codproducto int(5) NOT NULL,

    nrocliente bigint(10) NOT NULL,

    cantidad tinyint(100),

    id_venta int NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,

    PRIMARY KEY (id_venta),

    INDEX (codproducto),

    FOREIGN KEY (codproducto) REFERENCES producto (codproducto),

    INDEX (nrocliente),

    FOREIGN KEY (nrocliente) REFERENCES clientes (nrocliente)

    )
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> #1005 - No puedo crear tabla `empresa`.`venta` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalles…)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creamos una FK constraint, MySQL requiere un index en la tabla referencia y en la referenciada. En la tabla que hace la referencia (**venta**) se crea automaticamente dicho indice pero en la referenciada (tabla **producto** y **cliente**) tenes que crearlos manualmente.

Intentá agregar este indice antes de la creación de la tabla **venta**:

```
CREATE INDEX index_producto ON producto(codproducto);
CREATE INDEX index_cliente ON cliente(nrocliente);
```

Comment: Me aparece:

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1061 - Nombre de clave duplicado 'index_cliente'

//me sale lo mismo con la otra clave//

#1061 - Nombre de clave duplicado 'index_producto'

Comment: @FranciscoMonges Probaste cambiarle el nombre a los indices? Ponerle algo así como **idx_producto_pk** y **idx_cliente_pk**